# Where is the Workflow log in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

NetSuite help suggests this "To access the workflow execution log, select the record for the workflow, click the System Information and Workflow History subtabs, and click the Log link for the state you want to view. "

I don't see where this is. Sorry if it sound a noob question, this is the first time i am trying to build a workflow.
PS: This is for a Bin Transfer record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The System Information >> Workflow history tabs are available on other transactions such as Sales Order and Purchase orders, but not for Bin Transfers. Just discovered it...

Answer (score 0):

Log Link will be seen when workflow run on the record, path is

The System Information >> Workflow history

Answer (score 0):

The 1st configuration step would be to open the Workflow in question and check the checkbox- "Enable Logging" on the global level of the workflow (edit main workflow)[Enable logging on workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyLau.png) . Please see the screenshot 1 for your reference.

The 2nd step would be to navigate to the record on which this workflow is active. Navigate to system information --> Workflow history --> Log (which is a link, which when open shows you all the actions e.g. when the workflow was triggered, what actions were rejected due to conditions not being met etc.)[image: Check workflow logs on a record] Please see screenshot 2 for reference